Cannot deploy Express on Vecel, error code 404
Need help deploy my express server on vercel.
I change my express files following vercel's documentation, however, it still show error 404.
My git:https://github.com/badao729/AcademyAtlas-server.git
vercel deploy log message
error code
I added vercel.json, but still show error.
All endpoint I checked all show error 404.
